# Dynamic Linq Order By user defined sequence

Tags: linq, sorting, sql-order-by, dynamic-linq

I have dynamic linq query with OrderBy.

```
 .AsQueryable().OrderBy("FullName", asc)
```

After sorting by FullName, I need to sort by status (something like ThenBy()). Status may have vales e.g. "A", "B", "C", "D"
But I need to sort in following sequence "B", "A", "D", "C". As result can't use asc/desc in this case.

Comment: My first chould would be to add a numeric sort field to your status table.

Comment: From what source (ORM?) do you get the Queryable from?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following:

a) Define the collection of your keys in the order you want

```
var keys = new string[]{"B", "A", "D", "C"};
```

b) Use the above keys to define the custom order of your data

```
var result = yourCollection.AsQueryable()
                           .OrderBy("FullName", asc)
                           .ThenBy(x=>keys.IndexOf(x.Status));
```

Comment: Thank you, but here is Dynamic Linq, I cannot use ThenBy.

Comment: Why not? you can just cast the `IQueryable` after the `OrderBy("FullName", asc)` back to an `IQueryable<TEntity>`